# When trying to allow rotation to my IK rig it jumbles up my bones and mesh, why is it doing this? What can I do?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I'm quite a noob at rigging just FYI.
In my IK rig I have 7 bones in the spine of a robot with 7 vertebrae that are joined into one object parented to the 7 bones, I have one skull bone that those 7 bones are parented to where I added Inverse Kinematics with an empty controller. [image: as shown here]

This rig seems to work fairly well as long as I am only moving it side to side on an axis, but I do want to allow rotation as well. When I allow Rotation in the IK options it totally jumbles up any mesh that are connected to the bones.[image: As shown here]

I have no idea what's causing this and how I could get it to look and function normally. Also I'm not really sure where to put the pole target in this set up because I end up with a similar jumbled mess when I try to set it but it seems to be okay without it. How can I fix this?

Thankyou

Comment: Why do you want/need an IK constraint for the head?

Comment: I just figured an IK on the head would help me control the whole neck in a fluid way.

Comment: So you want to tilt the head and the neck should follow? The jumble is probably caused by the missing pole target. I guess you need to place it behind the head, choose it in the settings and adjust the *Pole Angle* value.

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out, all I had to do was rotate my ik controller until everything was in its original position and now everything seems to be working well. Not sure if i need the pole target at this point unless you think it would really improve things, it seems like it gives other people a lot of problems having it.